# Why does vscode say the asset does not exist? flutter

Tags: flutter

I did it in the android studio before. That's why I can't understand this doesn't work... Is this a kind of bug? or Am I doing wrong?
the "get packages" is the same as "pub get" in android studio. isn't it?
[assets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBrIa.png)

Comment: `lib` and `assets` folder should be siblings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assets folder is under the lib folder. It should be in the main folder.

Or you can edit your path like this:

```
assets:
  - lib/assets/bar.jpg
```

Comment: Don't feel like this. It is a super-normal situation for all developers.